# ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined Nest.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

when I am running `npm run test:e2e` in nestjs get  ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined error could you help me to find problem?

I used Graphql, Mongoose, Nest.js

```
import request from "supertest";
import { Test } from "@nestjs/testing";
import { INestApplication } from "@nestjs/common";
import { AppModule } from "../src/app.module";

describe("AppController (e2e)", () => {
   let app: INestApplication;

   beforeAll(async () => {
      const moduleFixture = await Test.createTestingModule({
         imports: [AppModule],
      }).compile();

      app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
      await app.init();
   });

   it("/GET /", () => {
      return request(app.getHttpServer())
         .get("/")
         .expect(200)
         .expect("Hello World!");
   });
});
```

Comment: there's nothing wrong with that snippet. You'll need to share us more info, like the stacktrace

Comment: It would be helpful to see the full error message and the code line(s) the error message refers to